# Current instance of CustomView in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

How can I retreive the "current instance" of my view (defined as `TextView`) in Ember.js app?

If I get it correctly, the router manages instantiating `textView` with correct context (I can access it in the handlebars template as `{{content}}`). Basically, I have several contacts in my messaging app and I need to hold array of messages for each of them.

View:

```
App.TextView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName : 'text',
    messages : [],
});
```

Router:

```
send : Ember.Route.extend({
    route:'/send',
    connectOutlets:function (router) {
        var conversationController = router.get('conversationController'),
             contact = conversationController.get('content');
        // contact is my context, it's ok here
        conversationController.connectOutlet('text', contact);
    }
)};
```

Comment: a TextView instance is created and returned after each call to 'conversationController.connectOutlet('text', contact)'.
Be warned here, I don't know if it's expected, but the messages property wil be shared between all view instances here.

Comment: `conversationController.get('view')` will return the current instance of your `TextView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `connectOutlets` is called on the `conversationController` controller, a `TextView` is created and set as a property on the `conversationController`, with the name of the Outlet:

If the Outlet has no name, it will be called "view":